# How to pass data from Main activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

I want to pass the name and number entered by the user to the `FakeRinger` class in my android app. I used the `putExtra()` method on the intent in the `fab.setOnClickListener`. Here's the code I am using in my `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";

    ImageView imageView;
    EditText number, name;
    Button setTimeButton;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    Calendar calendar;
    long selectedTimeInMillis;
    TimePickerDialog timePicker;
    String enteredName, enteredNumber;
    Intent intent;

    private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        setTimeButton = findViewById(R.id.set_time);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

        number = findViewById(R.id.number);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);

        enteredName = name.getText().toString().trim();
        enteredNumber = number.getText().toString().trim();

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, SELECT_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        setTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                        selectedTimeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                        if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                            hourOfDay = hourOfDay - 12;
                        }

                        if (minute < 10) {
                            String minuteStr = "0" + String.valueOf(minute);
                            minute = Integer.parseInt(minuteStr);
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "minute is :" + minute);
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, hourOfDay + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Selected time in millis:" + selectedTimeInMillis);
                    }
                }, hour, minute, false);
                timePicker.show();
            }
        });

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
                intent.putExtra("FAKE_NAME", enteredName);
                intent.putExtra("FAKE_NUMBER", enteredNumber);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                if (alarmManager != null) {
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, selectedTimeInMillis, pi);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your call has been placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.quick_call:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = null;
                if (imageUri != null) {
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                }
                Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `BroadcastReceiver` class

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String getFakeName = intent.getStringExtra("FAKE_NAME");
        String getFakeNumber = intent.getStringExtra("FAKE_NUMBER");

        Intent fakeRinger = new Intent();
        fakeRinger.setClassName("com.example.mani.fakecall", "com.example.mani.fakecall.FakeRinger");
        fakeRinger.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        fakeRinger.putExtra("USER_FAKE_NAME", getFakeName);
        fakeRinger.putExtra("USER_FAKE_NUMBER", getFakeNumber);
        context.startActivity(fakeRinger);

        Log.v("Yes, we are in", "Alarm reciever");
        Log.v("fake name is: ", getFakeName);
        Log.v("fake number is: ", getFakeNumber);
    }
}
```

And this is my `FakeRinger` Activity

```
public class FakeRinger extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView displayName;
    TextView displayNumber;
    Button alarmOffButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fake_ringer);

        displayName = findViewById(R.id.display_name);
        displayNumber = findViewById(R.id.display_number);

        String callName = getFakeName();
        String callNumber = getFakeNumber();

        displayName.setText(callName);
        displayNumber.setText(callNumber);

        alarmOffButton = findViewById(R.id.alarm_off);
        alarmOffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    private String getFakeName(){
        String contactName = null;
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            contactName = bundle.getString("USER_FAKE_NAME");
        }
        return contactName;
    }

    private String getFakeNumber(){
        String contactNumber = null;
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            contactNumber = bundle.getString("USER_FAKE_NUMBER");
        }
        return contactNumber;
    }
}
```

Still I am not able to display the name and number entered by user in the `FakeRinger` activity. Can anybody tell me where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Do your logs show the data passed correctly?

Comment: No, the logs don't show anything

Comment: Please move `Log.v("Yes, we are in", "Alarm reciever");` above the startActivity

Comment: I don't want to display them in the logs, i want to display them in the `FakeRinger` activity

Comment: Slow down. Test your code in smaller portions. By seeing the logs, you can know where your code is not working and where the values do exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move these two lines into the FAB click listener

```
enteredName = name.getText().toString().trim();
enteredNumber = number.getText().toString().trim();
```

Where you currently have them, the layout is empty, and you never assign those strings to anything else.

And if you see no logs from the AlarmReciever, then nothing is being passed to the next activity anyway

Comment: Thanks for your help @cricket_007. It works perfect :)

Comment: But how did this work. Can you ellaborate it a bit more ?

Comment: I already explained. OnCreate loads an empty XML page. Your EditTexts have no content for you to get. That's a key lesson for GUI programming - all your input fields are responsive, so you need to load them *in response to some event*, such as a button click